# Unable to scrape data from eastbay.com using BS4?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I've selected the brands that I am interested in and this URL was generated:

https://www.eastbay.com/category/mens/shoes.html?query=%3Arelevance%3Agender%3A200000%3AproductType%3A200005%3Abrand%3AChampion%3Abrand%3AConverse%3Abrand%3AFila%3Abrand%3AJordan%3Abrand%3ANew+Balance%3Abrand%3ANike%3Abrand%3ANike+SB%3Abrand%3APUMA%3Abrand%3AReebok%3Abrand%3ASalomon%3Abrand%3AThe+North+Face%3Abrand%3ATimberland%3Abrand%3AUGG%3Abrand%3AUnder+Armour%3Abrand%3AVans%3Abrand%3Aadidas%3Abrand%3Aadidas+Originals&

I'm trying to scrape data from this page, mainly the product page URLs (`href` attribute values of `a` elements with the class `Link--product`).

My first issue is that, using BS4, I was unable to get any data from the website.

Even running this simple test snippet (disregard most imports, they are used in the main program),

```
import requests
import csv
import io
import os
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from datetime import datetime
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
     'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36',
}

data = requests.get("https://www.eastbay.com/category/sport/casual/mens/shoes.html",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'lxml')

x = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'primary'}).text.strip()
print(x)
```

which should print the text in the first `span` element with the class `primary` (result should be `Nike Air Force 1 Low`), returns error `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10060, 'WSAETIMEDOUT')"))`, which should indicate that my headers are not being accepted by the host, but I've tried many different headers without success.

I got Selenium to work and display `Nike Air Force 1 Low` using this simple snippet:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.eastbay.com/category/sport/casual/mens/shoes.html") 
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='primary']")
print(x.text)
driver.close()
```

but I would really prefer using BS4 if it's possible. Does anyone know how to get BS4 to work with this website?

My second question is about pagination on this website. Near the bottom of the URL, there is a "Load More" button that makes a request to the API that then loads the next batch of products. However, the URL never changes. Can anyone help me with iterating over the batches so that all products, and not just the first 60, can be fetched?

I tried something like this, modified from another website's script that also has no pagination in the URL:

```
url = "https://www.eastbay.com/category/mens/shoes.html?query=%3Arelevance%3Agender%3A200000%3AproductType%3A200005%3Abrand%3AChampion%3Abrand%3AConverse%3Abrand%3AFila%3Abrand%3AJordan%3Abrand%3ANew+Balance%3Abrand%3ANike%3Abrand%3ANike+SB%3Abrand%3APUMA%3Abrand%3AReebok%3Abrand%3ASalomon%3Abrand%3AThe+North+Face%3Abrand%3ATimberland%3Abrand%3AUGG%3Abrand%3AUnder+Armour%3Abrand%3AVans%3Abrand%3Aadidas%3Abrand%3Aadidas+Originals"

qsp = {
    'currentPage': 1,
    'pageSize': 100,
    'timestamp': 3
}

container = []


for page_content in range(0,1500,60):
    qsp['currentPage'] = page_content
    res = requests.get(url,params=qsp,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36"})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    for item in soup.select(".c-product-card a"):
        container.append("https://www.eastbay.com"+item['href'])

    for items in soup.select("script"):
        sauce = BeautifulSoup(items.text,"lxml")
        for elem in sauce.select(".c-product-card a"):
            container.append("https://www.eastbay.com"+elem['href'])

print(container)
```

but this results in either an empty list or just gets stuck.

I have checked the XHR and Fetch tab within the Network tab in Chrome Dev tools, and I can see what kind of request clicking on the "Load More" button is making, but I am clueless when it comes to passing query string parameters to iterate over the batches of products.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if  page uses JavaScript then you can't use requsets+BS. You can run Selenium and get HTML from Selenium (page_source) and use in BS. But Selenium has own methods to get data from page.

Comment: harder way: JavaScript reads data from some url. If you find this url in DevTools in Chrome/Firefox then you can try to read it with `requests`. But JavaScript may need also cookies, session, and it can encrypt data so sometimes it is hard to do the same with requests.

Comment: I'll see if I can use Selenium for a part of my program and BS4 for the other part. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea with XHR. Here's how you can get it, and then iterate over that json format to print out the desired outputs:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.eastbay.com/api/products/search'

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36'}

payload = {
'query': ':relevance:sport:Casual:gender:200000:productType:200005',
'currentPage': '1',
'pageSize': '200',
'timestamp': '4'}

jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

totalPages = jsonData['pagination']['totalPages']
totalResults = jsonData['pagination']['totalResults']

print ('%s total results to aquire' %totalResults)


for page in range(1,totalPages+1):
    payload = {
            'query': ':relevance:sport:Casual:gender:200000:productType:200005',
            'currentPage': page,
            'pageSize': '200',
            'timestamp': '4'}


    jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

    try:
        for product in jsonData['products']:
            print (product['name'])
    except:
        print ('Products not found on this request')
```

Comment: When I try to copy and paste this code, I get `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', OSError("(10060, 'WSAETIMEDOUT')"))` error. I am using a VPN to access this website, as it won't let me access it without one from Europe. Could the problem lie in the VPN? The website works when I open it in a browser after turning on the VPN. Could you please tell me what output you're receiving with this code? Thank you so much.

Comment: it possibly could be the VPN. I'm receiving an output of all the product data related to the query. The code above is just printing out the product name.

Comment: I tried using a different VPN and it worked. I also managed to use the data your code returns to construct the product page URLs and I'm now in the process of getting data from them. Thank you very much, I couldn't have done it without your help.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad it helped you out.